# What is the significance of adding Exclamation? It does not change the operation without it

Tags: jupyter, google-colaboratory

What is the significance of adding Exclamation?
It does not change the operation without it.

```
ls
```

sample_data/

```
! ls
```

sample_data

Comment: For some common shell commands like `ls` it isn't needed, but for other stuff you need it.

Comment: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html

Comment: `ls` is actually `%ls` with `automagic` on.  `!ls` runs a shell command.  The results may be the same, but the execution is a bit different.

Comment: And I note that you mention both Jupyter and Google Colab in your tags. Be aware there are nuances as Google Colab branched off from Jupyter way back and hasn't incorporated significant upgrades made in Jupyter, as far as I last knew. In open source Jupyter for installations you now should use the magic command `%pip install` , or `%conda install` depending on your main package manager, for installations within a jupyter cell. NOT THE EXCLAMATION POINT. Automagics will nicely handle it properly if there is no symbol. I think Google doesn't have this magic that handles the environment better.

Comment: With the system command I can collect the results, e.g. `x=!ls`, where `x` is then a list.  `x=%ls` displays the results but returns `None`.  `x=ls` is a syntax error.  (I'm testing this in a `ipython` console.